# jquery умный счетчик символов

Tags: jquery, javascript

что бы сделать простой счетчик, делаем так:

```
$(function() {
$('#keyup').keyup(function(){
    $('.keyup').text('Введено: ' + $(this).val().length);
});
```

а как сделать его умным? что б он до 50 символов не показывал счетчик, после 50 показывал черным, после 100 показывал красным

Comment: есть такая замечательная штука в программировании - условия ;)

Comment: умное замечание, но я потратил уже 4 часа и у меня не заработало ничего, поэтому пошел на форум.

Comment: и у меня не заработало ничего

Может это означает что надо **дальше учить javascript**, а не идти на форум?

Comment: извините, что Вы тут делаете?
Вы забыли назначения форума.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$('#keyup').keyup(function(){
  var l = $(this).val().length;
  if (l < 50) { $('.keyup').hide(); return false; }
  var c = (l > 100) ? '#FF0000' : '#000000';
  $('.keyup').show().text('Введено: ' + l).css({color: c});
});
```

Примерно так, могут быть неточности.

Comment: спасибо, заработало вроде нормально.

Answer (score 1):

гыгы :))) Тууупой счетчик :)))

делаем умный :

```
$(function() {
$('#keyup').keyup(function(){
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if(len && len > 59 && len < 100) 
            $('.keyup').text('Введено: ' + len);
    else if (len && len > 100)
            $('.keyup').text('<font color="red">Введено: ' + len + '</font>');
    else return;

});
```

так проще всего, но быдлокод :)

Comment: ксати в браузере почему то так и пишется <font color="red">
а не превращается в тег html

Comment: гыгы :)) Не заметил :))) Вы же text вставляете :)
Молодец, товарищ... сбил меня с толку :)
Случаем, под .keyup не input / textarea скрывается ? :D